# How is the "Helpful flags" count on the Election page calculated?

Tags: bug, election, flagging

I only ask because the number displayed by my nomination is different from that on my profile. Are these only recent helpful flags, or some such? Potential bug?

Comment: Can confirm that. ~30 (helpful) flags missing.

Comment: I can confirm that too, about 70 flags missing.